# IntelliJ DataGrip how to enable add row?

Tags: intellij-idea, datagrip

I use the DataGrip for some days now and i really like it but it has a suspicious behavior. In some tables i open i can't add new rows. In other tables of the same database it works fine.

The add row button is disabled and so i can't add new rows.
If there are rows in the table i can remove them but still can't add new.

I searched the web for that but can't find any hint why this happens.

Do somebody know why is that? Is there a configuration or setup to enable adding rows for specific tables?

Comment: Can you tell what is the difference between the table you can add and you cannot? May be it is the point of rules?

Answer (score 33):

you have to refresh your database model by synchronizing. right click your scheme then click synchronize (ctrl + alt + y) then you can see add new row button is not disabled.

Answer (score 0):

For me this occurred when the content essentially got messed up, it was a csv been edited in the view or within the standard view.  Some commas got removed so it destroyed the validity of the content.

When I went to add a new row, nothing happened in the data view but in the normal view I noticed random commas getting inserted.  Honestly just got lucky to notice this, wouldn't have had a clue otherwise!

Comment: Could you elaborate and provide some more details and steps to reproduce?