# DataGrip Unable to add new rows from the tool

Tags: datagrip

I am trying to add new rows through the UI. However, the add new row button is disabled for me. How do you enable the add new row button? Tried to use the shortcut command + N, but doesn't work for me.

Note: I tried to synch the schema, still doesn't work for me. Also, I am able to insert into the database by running scripts so there is no permission issue unless I need to explicitly let datagrip configure for inserts.
I also tried all the steps, still not able to insert:

1. Click  Command + D to clone on the toolbar.
2. Right-click the table and select Add New Row from the context menu.
   Press⌘N.

[image]

Comment: is the table locked ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IntelliJ DataGrip how to enable add row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41188333/intellij-datagrip-how-to-enable-add-row)

Comment: No, the table isn't locked. I tried to synch the schema as mentioned in the post but that doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Please, show a query to get this result.

Comment: What database do you use? Aren't you in Read-only mode?

Answer (score 0):

Most of UI database need unique keys to enable insert / update / delete.

Look at also the source if it's a query non updatable.